# Why can I not see captured image?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I am facing a weird problem.

I am able to load and show image. Also, I am able to capture image but I cannot see image in display. The camera connected fine and capture image fine but cannot see image.

My system is window 10- 64 bit with opencv 3.3.0.

Code is below.

```
int main()
{

    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "camera didn't connected." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int nFrame = 0;

    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("orgin102.jpg");

    cv::imshow("image", image);

    cvWaitKey(0);

    while (true) {

        cv::Mat origin;

        cap >> origin;

        //flip orign 
        flip(origin, origin, 1);

        nFrame++;

        cv::imshow("image", origin);

        //if (cv::waitKey(27) >= 0) break;

        cvWaitKey(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by changing parameter of cap.

here it is

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(1);
```

For some systems, 0 index shows as first camera. and for others index 1 shows first camera.

Hope this  helps. 
Cheers!